# Iterate perimeter of rectangle

Tags: javascript, loops, geometry, pseudocode

Say you got a rectangle, `width=10, height=20` and want to get the coordinates of every pixel in the perimeter. You could have done it with 4 for loops, but isn't there a better, neater way?

```
for(x=0; x<width; x++){
    doSomethingWith(x,0)
}
for(y=0; y<height; y++){
    doSomethingWith(0,y)
}
for(x=1; x<width; x++){
    doSomethingWith(x,height)
}
for(y=1; y<height; y++){
    doSomethingWith(width,y)
}
```

I'll use javascript but help in pseudocode or other languages are appreciated.

[image: image of rectangle with colored perimiter]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with just two `for` loops:

```
for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  doSomethingWith(x, 0)
  doSomethingWith(x, height - 1)
}
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  doSomethingWith(0, y)
  doSomethingWith(width - 1, y)
}
```

Example:

```js
var x, y, width = 10, height = 20;
for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  doSomethingWith(x, 0)
  doSomethingWith(x, height - 1)
}
for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
  doSomethingWith(0, y)
  doSomethingWith(width - 1, y)
}
function doSomethingWith(x, y) {
  var b = document.createElement("div");
  b.className = "block";
  b.style.left = (x * 10) + "px";
  b.style.top = (y * 10) + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(b)
}
```

```css
.block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
var x = -1; var y = -1; var width = 10; var height = 20;
while (++x < width)
  [[x,0], [x, height-1]].forEach((params) => doSomethingWith.apply(this, params));
while (++y < height)
  [[0, y], [width-1, y]].forEach((params) => doSomethingWith.apply(this, params));

function doSomethingWith(x, y) {
  var b = document.createElement("div");
  b.className = "block";
  b.style.left = (x * 10) + "px";
  b.style.top = (y * 10) + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(b)
}
```

```js
var x = -1; var y = -1; var width = 10; var height = 20;
while (++x < width)
  [[x,0], [x, height-1]].forEach((params) => doSomethingWith.apply(this, params));
while (++y < height)
  [[0, y], [width-1, y]].forEach((params) => doSomethingWith.apply(this, params));

function doSomethingWith(x, y) {
  var b = document.createElement("div");
  b.className = "block";
  b.style.left = (x * 10) + "px";
  b.style.top = (y * 10) + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(b)
}
```

```css
.block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```